# oblique derivative smoothness of harmonic functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Let $Q$ be a domain in the half-space $\mathbb R^n\cap\{x_n>0\}$ and part of its boundary
is a domain $S$ on the hyperplane $x_n=0$. Let $u\in C(\bar Q)\cap C^2( Q)$ satisfy $\Delta u=0$ in $Q$ and for some fixed $\bar b=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$, $b_n\ne0$,
$$
\lim_{x_n\to0+}\frac{ \partial u}{\partial\bar b}=f\in C(S)\quad \hbox{a.e. on $S$}.
$$
Does it follow that $\frac{ \partial u}{\partial\bar b}$ is continuous up to $S$?

A special case: if
$$
\lim_{x_n\to0+}\frac{ \partial u}{\partial x_n}=0\quad \hbox{a.e. on $S$},
$$
will $u$ be smooth on $Q\!\cup\! S$? It is also enough to show that $\frac{ \partial u}{\partial x_n}$ is continuous up to $S$.

Comment: What is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \bar{b}}$? The directional derivative?

Comment: @user7530 $~$yes.

Comment: I'm missing something: isn't $u$ analytic, so that all of its directional derivatives are certainly continuous?

Comment: @user7530 in $\Omega$ yes. But it is not assumed that $u$ is analytic on $S$.

Answer (score 0):

This is true by standard elliptic regularity results, for instance, by the Agmon-Douglis-Nirenberg theory. Even more is true: $u$ is smooth and partial derivatives of all orders are continuous up to $S$.

Comment: They deal with solutions in Holder spaces. And prove Schauder type estimates. Which assume that solutions are from $C^{m_0,\alpha}$. I doubt there is anything about $f\in C(S)$. As for the special case I would be grateful if you could show how exactly it follows that $\frac{ \partial u}{\partial x_n}$ is continuous up to $S$.

Comment: @Andrew: I overlooked the condition $f\in C(S)$, but I am pretty sure your statement is true. I take back the smoothness statement though. I am not sure what you mean by "which assume that solutions are from ..." but the Schauder estimates you mention imply additional regularity, given that the solution has some minimal regularity to start with.